# JSON writes converter in Play application doesn't accept type

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play framework application and want to create a `Writes` converter in order to transform some models to JSON. What I have so far:

```
implicit val locationWrites = new Writes[Board] {
  def writes(board: Board) = Json.obj(
    "gameSize" -> board.n,
    "fields" -> Seq(FieldWithCoords((1,2,3), "field", true)) // error for this line
  )
}

implicit val fieldWrites = new Writes[FieldWithCoords] {
  def writes(field: FieldWithCoords) = Json.obj(
    "coords" -> field.coords.toString,
    "player" -> field.p, 
    "isHighlighted" -> field.highlighted
  )
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

> type mismatch; found: Seq[util.FieldWithCoords]  required:
>   play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper  Note: implicit value
>   locationWrites is not applicable here because it comes after the
>   application point and it lacks an explicit result type

As you can see, there is a conversion for FieldWithCoords. How could I fix this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**edit:**

"fields" should contain multiple items later on, therefore the `Seq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the writes combinators is considered better practice that creating the JSON directly:

```
implicit lazy val fieldWrites: Writes[FieldWithCoords] = (
  (__ \ "coords").write[String] and
  (__ \ "player").write[String] and
  (__ \ "isHighlighted").write[Boolean]
).apply(field => (field.coords.toString, field.p, field.highlighted))

implicit lazy val locationWrites: Writes[Board] = (
  (__ \ "gameSize").write[Int] and
  (__ \ "fields").write[Seq[FieldWithCoords]]
).apply(board => (board.n, Seq(FieldWithCoords((1,2,3), "field", true))
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler needs to implicitly convert your `Seq[FieldWithCoords]` to a `JsValueWrapper`. I was able to get it compiling by providing explicit result types to give it the little extra nudge it needed for the implicits to kick in.

```
implicit val fieldWrites: Writes[FieldWithCoords] = new Writes[FieldWithCoords] {
  def writes(field: FieldWithCoords) = Json.obj(
    "coords" -> field.coords.toString,
    "player" -> field.p, 
    "isHighlighted" -> field.highlighted
  )
}

implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Board] = new Writes[Board] {
  def writes(board: Board) = Json.obj(
    "gameSize" -> board.n,
   "fields" -> Seq(FieldWithCoords((1,2,3), "field", true)) // error for this line
  )
}
```